# Tracking the number of shortcodes for a list?

Tags: functions, shortcode

I want to have a list of my top 10 favorite resources. Each resource is going to be in a shortcode

[resource name="Resoruce Name" link="http:/"]Why I love the resource[/resoruce]

However, I want to number them, and I'd like to just write them in the order I want and re-organize as time goes on without having to change the #s. Can I use some type of counter variable in the Functions.php to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap an `<ol>` around them and have your [resource] shortcode create an `<li>` for each one.

Editor view:

```
<ol>
    [resource name="Resource" link="http://foo.com"]Why I love it[/resource]
    [resource name="Another Resource" link="http://footwo.com"]Why I love this[/resource]
</ol>
```

HTML output:

```
<ol>
        <li><a href="http://foo.com">Resource</a><p>Why I love it</p></li>
        <li><a href="http://footwo.com">Another Resource</a><p>Why I love this</p></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I'll need to write a whole bunch of CSS because these are going to be some complex/involved formatting per resource, probably 300 words per resource with potentially tables and javascript expands

Comment: With shortcodes there's no way to set a counting variable. One alternative would be to use Advanced Custom Fields plugin which would let you drag and drop the resources, and in your theme template file that pulls them in to display them, you could set a counter variable in a `for($i=0; $i<count($resources); $i++)` style loop.

Comment: You could also set them as custom postmeta without the ACF plugin, but formatting would be more of a chore. ACF will let you include full editor areas for each field so you can include your tables, js, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification of what is possible , I want ahead and marked it correct and upvoted :)